# boot repair in Ubuntu 16.04, bootscript, and shimx64.efi

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, initramfs

I have damaged something after an nvidia driver update. After the reboot, it no longer brings up the display. The display remains black when I reboot (nothing showsup). I can still ssh to the machine and execute commands through terminal (no graphic interfacec). So it seems I have damaged something related to the graphics in the boot file. This is what I get when I try `sudo update-initramfs -u`:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
/usr/bin/objcopy:/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/objcopy: --change-section-vma .initrd=0x0000000003000000 never used
/usr/bin/objcopy: --change-section-vma .linux=0x0000000000040000 never used
/usr/bin/objcopy: --change-section-vma .cmdline=0x0000000000030000 never used
/usr/bin/objcopy: --change-section-vma .osrel=0x0000000000020000 never used
update-initramfs: Failed to generate Linuxium bootscript.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What nVidia card/chip? How did you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository or nVidia's .run file (not recommended). Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Here is the BootInfo Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5wyRyR8KKq/

Comment: And this is what I followed to install nvidia driver: https://github.com/williamFalcon/tensorflow-gpu-install-ubuntu-16.04

Comment: It looks like that installs the .run file which is nVidia's, not the Ubuntu preconfigured version. And not newest. But I do not know cuda and what dependencies it may have. With the .run you have to run dkms with every kernel update to in effect reinstall nVidia driver. Generally better to use ppa if you need newest driver, but again not sure about cuda requirements. your sda drive 2.7TB is not shown correctly. Is it gpt partitioned? Did you add a bios_grub to it so grub would correctly install to it?

Comment: Well, I have been given this machine to run some stuff which rely on nvidia and cuda. Not sure about the partitioning. Is there a way to fix the kernel?

Comment: You can check this: `dkms status` That will show which kernel includes which drivers.  When using the .run installer, I have seen this, but do not know for sure if still current, as never used it myself. `nvidia-installer -f --dkms` That supposedly registers it with dkms. Post this on sda drive `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`